# Day time to string conversion

Tags: c#, datetime

What formatter should I use to get following day time string:

```
Mon Sep 13 11:51:00 2010
```

Thanks.

Comment: See [this MSDN entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
.ToString("ddd MMM d hh:mm:ss yyyy")
```

use dd to get a prefixed 0 for days 1...9

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("ddd MMM dd hh:mm:ss:00 yyyy")
```

Reference link - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/DateTime_Patterns.aspx